# Is ceph replication based on nodes or disks?

Tags: replication, ceph

Im currently evaluating storage systems for xenserver. Because data replication is important in the case of a failure i have a question regarding replication in ceph.

As far as i know every disk in a node is an osd by itself (disks are not in any raid configuration). Is the ceph replication algorithm aware of the fact that 2 osd's are on the same node so not replicating the data on these osd's?

Minimal Example:
2 nodes with 2 disks each.
Because of the non raid setup each disk is a osd -> 4 osd's.
Node A: OSD1, OSD2; Node B: OSD3, OSD4.
I set the replication amount to 2 and save an object into ceph.
Will the object be saved and replicated on so that in case of a node failure the data is completely accessible?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: In addition to the answers I'd recommend to not run pools with size 2 in production. It's only a matter of time until you'll run into issues, the mailing list is full of such failures. Either run replicated pools with size 3 (or more, of course) or erasure-coded pools according to your resiliency requirements.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes
2. You can define the policy to replicate by node, racks, datacenters, etc.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the CRUSH replication rule(replicated_ruleset) state that the replication is at the **host** level. You can check this be exporting the crush map:

```
ceph osd getcrushmap -o /tmp/compiled_crushmap
crushtool -d /tmp/compiled_crushmap -o /tmp/decompiled_crushmap
```

The map will displayed these info:

```
rule replicated_ruleset {
        ruleset 0
        type replicated
        min_size 1
        max_size 10
        step take default
        step chooseleaf firstn 0 type host
```

The types of replication is listed in the at the beginning of the map:

```
# types
type 0 osd
type 1 host
type 2 chassis
type 3 rack
type 4 row
type 5 pdu
type 6 pod
type 7 room
type 8 datacenter
type 9 region
type 10 root
```

In order to get to HEALTH_OK state and have your object replicated based on your rules, you have to change the type of replication to **osd** in your specific case. The map can be recompiled by running:

```
crushtool -c /tmp/decompiled_crushmap -o /tmp/compiled_crushmap
ceph osd setcrushmap -i /tmp/compiled_crushmap
```

You can find more info about how to play with the CRUSH map in the ceph documentation: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/operations/crush-map/

The placement of a specific object can be found using:

```
ceph osd map {pool-name} {object-name}
```

If you want to check a map of all the object you can do that by looking at the placement group dump(consider your own info to be displayed):

```
ceph pg dump | awk  '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $15 "\t" $16}'
```

Regarding the OSD, you can consider an OSD any type of logical of physical storage unit(folder/partition/Logical Volume/disk/LUN)